# How do I set the default value for an optional argument in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a Javascript function with an optional argument, and I want to assign the optional argument a default value. How can I assign it a default value?

I thought it would be this, but it doesn't work:

```js
function(nodeBox,str = "hai")
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This now works in ES6

Comment: Yeah got to know about this recently.  http://es6-features.org/#DefaultParameterValues

Comment: I would however try and keep the logic in the parameters to a minimum.....

Answer (score 158, accepted):

If `str` is null, undefined or 0, this code will set it to "hai"

```
function(nodeBox, str) {
  str = str || "hai";
.
.
.
```

If you also need to pass 0, you can use:

```
function(nodeBox, str) {
  if (typeof str === "undefined" || str === null) { 
    str = "hai"; 
  }
.
.
.
```

Comment: @Roayl: This will also work for `false` if that is what you mean.

Comment: No default should be true. I mean if i will not pass parametr, it should take true

Comment: OK i will take default as false only. No need set to false. Default it will take as false.

Comment: It would be counter intuitive to have a variable you do NOT pass end up as true.

Answer (score 32):

**ES6 Update** - ES6 ([ES2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)) allows for [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

The following will work just fine in an ES6 (ES015) environment...

```
function(nodeBox, str="hai")
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this with [ArgueJS](https://github.com/zvictor/ArgueJs):

```
function (){
  arguments = __({nodebox: undefined, str: [String: "hai"]})

  // and now on, you can access your arguments by
  //   arguments.nodebox and arguments.str
}
```